mgt-react Person component presence not updating
I'm having an React based SPA where I can successfully show the Person component and it also shows the presence but when the presence state changes, the new state is only shown on rerender.
<Person personQuery="me" showPresence={true} personCardInteraction="hover" />
Is this supposed to work? If yes, do I have do do anything else to make the updates come in?
I tried to call registerMgtPersonComponent() function but this does not change anything.

The presence: showPresence={true} looks like it has a hardcoded value - what do you mean by "when the presence state changes"? It can't change when it's hardcoded...

What I mean is, when I change the presence state in Teams. The showPresence is only a property to make the Person component show the presence.

Oh, okay, I think I understand. Where is the presence state coming from? Where and how is it stored in your app? You mentioned Teams - is it the Microsoft Teams you mean? Are you implementing some sort of integrations with its API?

The Person component is part of the Microsoft Graph Toolkit and is showing information from Users including the Teams presence state.

Oh damn, I thought this was a React-specific problem, which I could help with, but unfortunately I don't know anything about Microsoft Graph Toolkit
